# Feed could not be found

Tags: errors, feed

The Facebook feed seems to be down on our website http://www.pcrg.org (in the footer- at the bottom of each page).

We receive the following error:

Unable to fetch the feed
Error :
A feed could not be found at http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=234367520793&format=rss20. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed.
RSS Feed currently unavailable.

We are not very tech savvy, as we are a small nonprofit.  Can you provide some guidance on how to get that up and running?

Thank you.

-Sam

Answer (score 1):

The Activity Feeds has been deprecated and no longer works after 23rd June, so this is why it would have stopped working.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity

This is probably the nearest thing you will be able to have that is similar to the Activity Feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin